# Lcd display shield, no characters

Tags: lcd

So, I've been trying to make an [Lcd display shield](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/image/cache/data/dealextreme/arduino-lcd-keyboard-shield-500x500.jpg) I got from ebay to work with arduino. Using this very simple code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

#define RSPin 8
#define EnablePin 9
#define DS4 4
#define DS5 5
#define DS6 6
#define DS7 7

#define LCDColumns 16
#define LCDRows 2

LiquidCrystal lcd(RSPin, EnablePin,DS4,DS5,DS6,DS7);

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(LCDColumns, LCDRows); //Configure the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Hello, World!");
}

void loop()
{

}
```

Actually I've tried several simple examples, checked pins physically to make sure I'm using the right order, But no luck. backlight is on, no characters at all. Am I missing something? Or should just contact the seller to send another shield.

Comment: My guess: wrong contrast settings (on blue potentiometer)

Comment: I've tried rotate it, doesnt seems to do anything

Answer (score 1):

So, after some close inspection I noticed that the blue potentiometer wasnt soldered in correctly. Also, its needs to be turned quiet a lot to have some effect. Might replace it completely. But now it works!

Comment: Usually, PCB based potentiometers require many turns (~25) to cover the full range.  If a pot has been used a lot, a poor soldering joint will indeed come loose.  A super poor soldering joint comes loose without any help from the pot.